# В чем ошибка? В компиляторе правильно, на сайте выдеаёт ошибку

Tags: python

Решил задачу на stepik, вводил данные - всё работает, ввожу в меню с ответом и пишет

> Failed test #7 of 16. Wrong answer
>
> Напишите программу, на вход которой подаётся список чисел одной
> строкой. Программа должна для каждого элемента этого списка вывести
> сумму двух его соседей. Для элементов списка, являющихся крайними,
> одним из соседей считается элемент, находящий на противоположном конце
> этого списка. Например, если на вход подаётся список "1 3 5 6 10", то
> на выход ожидается список "13 6 9 15 7" (без кавычек).
>
> Если на вход пришло только одно число, надо вывести его же.
>
> Вывод должен содержать одну строку с числами нового списка,
> разделёнными пробелом.
> Может я что-то не так сделал?
> Вот код

```
s = input().split()
lens = len(s)
start = 0
end = -1
g = []
i = 0
k = i + 2
if lens == 1:
    print(*s)
elif lens > 1:
    for i in range(lens):
        if s[i] == s[start]:
            g.append(int(s[1]) + int(s[-1]))
            continue
        if ((s[i] != s[start]) or (s[i] != s[lens-1])) and k < lens:
            g.append(int(s[i-1]) + int(s[k]))
            k += 1
    for j in range(lens):
        if s[j] == s[end]:
            g.append(int(s[-2]) + int(s[0]))
print(*g)
```

Comment: `s[i] == s[start]` - это что, вы проверяете на первый элемент? а кто сказал, что они уникальные?

Comment: @splash58 да, вы правы, не подумал)

Comment: а вообще, если i - текущий индекс, можно просто брать `[i-1]` и `[(i+1)%len(lst)]`

Comment: @splash58 вы про условие? в первом и последнем я просто решил написать так (i == 0) и (i == lens-1)

Comment: нет, так можно брать элементы - если i ноль, получится -1 - последний элемент, а если последний то (i+1)%len(lst) даст 0 - первый элемент

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тест:

```
$ echo 1 1 | python pairwise-sum.py
2 2 2 2
```

Напечатано четыре числа в ответе, а не два, как должно быть. Это потому что в коде везде сравниваются значения (`s[i] == s[start]`), а должны сравниваться индексы (`i == start`). Пока все элементы в массиве уникальны, дефект не заметен.

Если убрать обращения к элементам списка в сравнениях, убрать второй цикл (в котором срабатывает только одна итерация), вынести расчёт первой суммы из цикла (ему там делать нечего) и сразу преобразовать строки в числа, получится такой код:

```
s = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
n = len(s)
if n <= 1:
    print(*s)
else:
    g = []
    g.append(s[-1] + s[1])
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        g.append(s[i - 1] + s[i + 1])
    g.append(s[-2] + s[0])
    print(*g)
```

Заметьте что `range` можно начать с нуля, тогда первая итерация сделает туже работу что `g.append` перед циклом:

```
    ...
    g = []
    for i in range(0, n - 1):
        g.append(s[i - 1] + s[i + 1])
    g.append(s[-2] + s[0])
    ...
```

Обращение `s[i + 1]` можно поменять на `s[i + 1 - n]`. Пример для `n = 6`, `i` пробегает значения от нуля до четырёх (`range(n - 1)`). В последней строки реальные индексы по которым делается обращение в `s`. Они совпадают с `i + 1`:

> ```
> i              :  0  1  2  3  4
> i + 1          :  1  2  3  4  5
> i + 1 - 6      : -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
> реальный индекс:  1  2  3  4  5
> ```

Если в `range` поднять увеличить на единицу правый край диапазона, последняя итерация цикла сделает ту же работу что и `g.append` после цикла:

```
    ...
    g = []
    for i in range(0, n):
        g.append(s[i - 1] + s[i + 1 - n])
    ...
```

Цикл теперь переписывается в виде списочного выражения:

```
    ...
    g = [s[i - 1] + s[i + 1 - n] for i in range(n)]
    ...
```

Список не нужен, вместо него генератор:

```
s = tuple(map(int, input().split()))
n = len(s)
if n <= 1:
    print(*s)
else:
    print(*(s[i - 1] + s[i + 1 - n] for i in range(n)))
```

Такая получилась индексация.